# Wordpress Change permalink after enter post title or change option in custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

Please see an image below:
[image]

[image]
I've created 2 custom post types they called automaker and car-line (1 automaker has many car-line). I want to when I create new car-line post, the permalink will get value is selected of automaker and change it from http://myhost.com/aotungchao/doi-xe/corrola/ to http://myhost.com/aotungchao/mua-ban-oto/toyota/corrola/ (it means that change doi-xe to mua-ban-oto/toyota). Do the same with change select automaker option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order the get the url structure you are after, I would suggest using the built in wordpress categories.

For example:

Parent Category = Cars; Child Category = Toyoto; Post title = Corolla

Would give you a url of `categories/cars/toyota/corolla/`

To remove the categories part, go to settings->permalink and place `./` in as the category name. Doing that will remove categories and give you a url that looks like the following:
`http://www.sitename.com/cars/toyota/corolla`.

You can also create a custom taxonomy for car brands and assign that to your cars custom post type. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies - look for Custom Taxonomies. Going this route will allow you to set a custom slug as well.